# Only run CSS transform when key is down - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, transform

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pane = $(document),         
        box = $("#hero"),               //Our character
        w = pane.width() - box.width(), //Width
        d = {},                         //Empty object
        angle = 0;


        var newr = function(a, b){
            return (a == 37) ? angle += 0.5 : (b == 39) ? angle -= 0.5 : angle;
        }
        $(window).keydown(function(e) { 
            d[e.which] = true;
        });
        $(window).keyup(function(e) { 
            d[e.which] = false; 
        });

        setInterval(function() {
            box.css({
                transform: function(index,value) { return "rotate(" + newr(37, 39) + "deg)"; }
            });
        }, 20);
});
```

My goal is to activate the transformation as soon as I hit either the **left** or **right** arrow key, and stop rotating when the key is released. The way it is now it rotates constantly.

**[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/nCEWu/5/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The reason it wasn't working properly was because in the `newr(a, b)` function i started out by checking if the first parameter `a == 37`, Meaning that when i called the function with 37 as my first parameter - it will always be true. Here is the correct function:

```
var newr = function(a, b){
    return (d[a]) ? angle += 0.5 : (d[b]) ? angle -= 0.5 : angle;
 }
```

Comment: I was just about to post a very similar sample. Actually it should be `return (d[a]) ? angle += 0.5 : (d[b]) ? angle -= 0.5 : angle;` for the right arrow also to work :)

Comment: Thats Ok mate. Happens to even the best of us :)